# Retrieving json from stringified javascript function returned in http response

Tags: java, javascript, json, rhino, javascript-engine

I have java (JDK6) code that sends an http get request with parameters.  The response that I get back is a javascript function that contains within it a json tree containing the response to the query parameters provided in the request like the following:

```
function JavascriptFunction() { return { "Root" : [ { ... ] }; }
```

I am attempting to bind to and execute the returned function using ScriptEngine api in java to retrieve the JSON node.

```
String response = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
ScriptEngine scriptEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("js");
scriptEngine.eval(response);

String hopeThisIsJson = (String)((Invocable)scriptEngine).invokeFunction("JavascriptFunction");
```

I get a ClassCastException because the "thing" being returned is of type sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.NativeObject.
I am trying to figure out how to ultimately convert this object that is returned from the invokeFunction method a json tree that was originally returned from the "JavascriptFunction" method.

Comment: Did you check the value of response here : String response = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());

Comment: I did check the value.  It was the stringified Javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript function is returning an object that is not JSON-encoded. You can try this:

```
String json = (String) scriptEngine.eval("JSON.stringify(JavascriptFunction());");
```

There's no such thing as a "JSON tree" in JavaScript code. That's a JavaScript object literal expression, which is to say that it's just a plain JavaScript object.

Comment: I tried what you suggested.  I get javax.script.ScriptException... ReferenceError: "JSON" is not defined.  The Rhino engine I have may not support the version of Javascript in which "JSON" exists.  In this case, I have to assume I cannot change versions.  Any alternatives to making using this?

Comment: @user2714310 yes, you need a 1.7 release of Rhino at least. If you can't change versions, you'll have to use a JSON toolkit, like the one available at json.org.